# Loading only 10 items in listview

Tags: android, listview, caching

The listview is loaded 100 pictures from the internet using a thread pool. How load only elements 10  to the extent necessary? And when scrolldown loading another 10 items? I'm using Lru cache for this

Comment: Post some code you tried and what was the problem with that please.

Comment: Sorry guys, you maybe a little confused. The answer is very simple, you need load the image in adapter(getView) . 10 pictures it was an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `limit` and `offset` for this:

Example:

suppose i want to fetch 10 records and after end the scroll will fetch another 10 records:

Define the offset variable:

```
private static int offset = 0;
```

when you bind the adapter at that pass the offset variable:

```
Select * from table limit 10 offset 0
```

So this will fetch only 10 records from 0-9 after that write below code for listview:

```
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;

            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {

                if (preLast != lastItem) { 
                    preLast = lastItem;

                    offset = offset + 10;

                    new fetchrecords().execute();

                } else {

                }
            }
        }

    });
```

so when go you to last position of list view item at that time it will call the method `fetchrecords()` and your `offset value is 10`.

So when this method calls at that time your offset value is 10.

so for next time your query is like:

```
select * from table limit 10 offset 10
```

So it will fetch other next 10 records.

Its done!!

Comment: I'd not recommend to do this,  unless you implement your own adapter, which you don't need to. the basic adapters lets you choose how many views you wanna keep in memory, and recycle them.

Comment: Yes.But if your database has thousands records then you can't load it all data at same time. At that time you have to do something like this. :-)

Comment: I still don't agree, you should limit the amount of workers for not fetching all data at once. and of course the use of limited memory LRU cache will prevent the memory overflow. if internet is slow you can also cancel image loading that are not relevant to the view anymore (when recycle a view cancel a pending request if exists)

Comment: Suppose i have put the limit of 100 records after that i need to load other 100 records at that time atleast i have to pass that i have got first 100 records so i need other 100 records...
Are you able to give me example for this ? so i can also understand your logic and view. `suppose i have 10000 records and i need to fetch only 100 records at first time after that i need to fetch other 100 records and so on.. ` can you explain with code? so we get an idea and used it in our app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an [adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)
2. Use [LruCache](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/) for image storage

It's all there hope you can take it from there.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Its just matter of changing the data source

when the first time list view is loaded

Fetch some 10 images and add that in data source for list view adapter

If scrolling is detected then fetch next 10 images and clear the listview adapete and add this new 10 again

or you can fetch all the image urls in one shot then according to the scrolling you can change the contents of data source of list view adapter

Answer (score 0):

no need to call all the data at once for your problem. you have to modify the api . make a webservice in such a way that only 10 data is shown at a time and this can be done by passing value from your app 
eg. during api calling pass 1 and server side should check if the value passed from android is 1 or 2 or... if the value is 1 (say) send 10 data using limit and if the value is 2 send another 10 data.
and in android side during scrolling your list view call api passing value and append those fetched data from api to your local list and show those to the list view. It saves the time and userdata aswell